# What voltage regulator is used for PoE Splitter and Switches?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, voltage-regulator, buck, poe

What is the working principle / hardware that is used for common PoE switches or PoE splitters. Please see following hardware examples:

[TP-Link PoE Switch](https://www.tp-link.com/de/business-networking/unmanaged-switch/tl-sg1005p/)

[RPI PoE Splitter](https://www.amazon.de/GeeekPi-PoE-Splitter-IEEE802-3af-Ethernet-Raspberry/dp/B0832SXPT7)

I am asking this question because I would like to have galvanic isolation. I think a switching buck regulator is used with common grounds on both ends.

Comment: You can have any principle you want. Isolated DC/DC converters do exist.

Comment: Silvertel have modules. TI and others have chip level solutions. The TP Link splitter i have uses a TI part. Buy one and open it up just like I did.

Comment: @Kartman thanks Kartman that is what I will do!